# Detailed view for each test set in a Rally project

Tags: testing, rally, summary

I am trying to figure out a way to have a Rally summary page displaying all test sets per the globally chosen project and particulary the exact numbers of pass/totals per test set.
I can display this using TestCaseStatus but the strings returned are not what I want. I read through some posts and it  seems that the only way to get this kind of details is to iterate through all test set test cases and check if they are passing or not on the client side; also to count them up.
Can anyone provide a working example of how to iterate through the test set test cases and count their last verdict BUT only for the current project not the last verdict in general?

Answer (score 0):

An example of a custom add that displays a grid of Test Sets based on a Project selection and then displays a grid of associated test cases and their test case results when a user double clicks on a row in a first grid is available in [this github repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/test-sets-by-project). You may copy the html file to a [custom html page](https://help.rallydev.com/custom-html) you create for this purpose.

Here is a js file:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',

        launch: function() {
            var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                layout: 'hbox',
                itemId: 'parentPanel',
                componentCls: 'panel',
                items: [
                    {
                    xtype: 'rallyprojectpicker',
                    fieldLabel: 'select project',
                        listeners:{
                            change: function(combobox){
                                if ( this.down('#g')) {
                                    console.log('grid exists');
                                    Ext.getCmp('g').destroy();
                                    console.log('grid deleted');
                                }
                                this.onProjectSelected(combobox.getSelectedRecord());
                            },
                            scope: this
                        }
                    },
            {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: 'Test Sets',
                    itemId: 'childPanel1'
            },
            {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: 'Test Cases',
            width: 600,
                    itemId: 'childPanel2'
            }
                ],
            });
            this.add(panel);
        },

        onProjectSelected:function(record){
            var project = record.data['_ref'];
            console.log('project', project);
            var testSetStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
        model: 'TestSet',
        fetch: ['FormattedID','Name', 'Project', 'TestCaseStatus', 'TestCases'],
        pageSize: 100,
        autoLoad: true,
        filters: [
            {
            property: 'Project',
            value: project
            }
            ],
        listeners: {
            load: this.onTestSetsLoaded,
            scope: this
        }
        }); 


        },

    onTestSetsLoaded:function(store, data){
                var testSets = [];
                Ext.Array.each(data, function(testset) {
                    var ts  = {
                        FormattedID: testset.get('FormattedID'),
                        _ref: testset.get('_ref'),  
                        Name: testset.get('Name'),
            TestCaseCount: testset.get('TestCases').Count,
            TestCaseStatus: testset.get('TestCaseStatus')
                    };
                    testSets.push(ts);
                 });
                this.updateGrid(testSets);

    },


        updateGrid: function(testSets){

        if (this.down('#g2')) {
            console.log('g2 exists');
            var store = this.down('#g2').getStore();
            store.removeAll();
        }


        var store = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                data: testSets,
                pageSize: 100
            });
        if (!this.down('#g')) {
        this.createGrid(store);
        }
        else{
        this.down('#g').reconfigure(store);
        }

    },

        createGrid: function(store){

        console.log("load grid", store);
        var that = this;
        var g = Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.Grid', {
            id: 'g',
            store: store
        });


        var g = Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.Grid', {
            id: 'g',
            store: store,

            columnCfgs: [
            {
               text: 'Formatted ID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID', xtype: 'templatecolumn',
            tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate')
            },
            {
            text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name'
            },
            {
                    text: 'Test Case Count', dataIndex: 'TestCaseCount',
                    },
            {
            text: 'TestCaseStatus', dataIndex: 'TestCaseStatus'
            }
            ],
            listeners: {
                celldblclick: function( grid, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex){
                var id = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex).get('FormattedID');
                console.log('id', id);
                that.getTestCases(id);     
                }
            }
        });
        this.down('#childPanel1').add(g);
    },
    getTestCases:function(id){
        var selectedTestSetStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
        model: 'TestSet',
        fetch: ['FormattedID','Name', 'TestCases'],
        pageSize: 100,
        autoLoad: true,
        filters: [
            {
            property: 'FormattedID',
            operator: '=',
            value: id
            }
            ],
        listeners: {
            load: this.onSelectedTestSetLoaded,
            scope: this
        }
        }); 
    },

    onSelectedTestSetLoaded:function(store, data){
        console.log('store',store);
        console.log('data',data);

        var selectedTestSets = [];
        var pendingTestCases = data.length;

         if (data.length ===0) {
        this.createTestSetGrid(selectedTestSets);  
         }

         Ext.Array.each(data, function(selectedTestset){ 
        var ts  = {
            FormattedID: selectedTestset.get('FormattedID'),
            TestCaseCount: selectedTestset.get('TestCases').Count,
            TestCases: [],
            ResultCount: 0 
        };
        var testCases = selectedTestset.getCollection('TestCases', {fetch: ['FormattedID','ObjectID', 'Results']});
        console.log('testCases:', selectedTestset.get('TestCases').Count, testCases); 
        testCases.load({
                    callback: function(records, operation, success){
                    Ext.Array.each(records, function(testcase){
                        console.log("testcase.get('FormattedID')", testcase.get('FormattedID'));  
                        console.log("testcase.get('Results').Count", testcase.get('Results').Count); 
                        ts.ResultCount = testcase.get('Results').Count; 
                        console.log('ts.ResultCount', ts.ResultCount);
                        ts.TestCases.push({_ref: testcase.get('_ref'),
                                    FormattedID: testcase.get('FormattedID'),
                                ObjectID: testcase.get('ObjectID')
                            });
                    }, this); 
                    --pendingTestCases;
                    if (pendingTestCases === 0) {
                        this.makeTestCaseStore(ts.TestCases);

                    }
                    },
                    scope: this
                });
        console.log('ts', ts);
        selectedTestSets.push(ts);
        },this);
    },

    makeTestCaseStore:function(testcases){
        console.log('makeTestCaseStore'); //ok
        if (testcases.length>0) {
        var idArray = [];
        _.each(testcases, function(testcase){
            console.log(testcase);
            console.log('OID', testcase['ObjectID']);
            idArray.push(testcase['ObjectID']);
            });
        console.log('idArray',idArray);

        var filterArray = [];
        _.each(idArray, function(id){
            filterArray.push(
            {
            property: 'ObjectID',
            value:id
            }
            )
        });
        console.log('filterArray', filterArray); //ok

         var filters = Ext.create('Rally.data.QueryFilter', filterArray[0]);

         filterArray = _.rest(filterArray,1);  

         _.each(filterArray, function(filter){
            filters = filters.or(filter)
            },1);
        var testCaseStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
            model: 'TestCase',
            fetch: ['FormattedID','Name', 'ObjectID', 'Results'],
            pageSize: 100,
            autoLoad: true,
            filters: [filters],
            listeners: {
            load: this.onTestCasesLoaded,
            scope: this
            }
        });
        }
        else{
        if (this.down('#g2')) {
            var store = this.down('#g2').getStore();
            store.removeAll();
            }
        }
    },


    onTestCasesLoaded:function(store,data){
        console.log('onTestCasesLoaded');
        console.log('store',store);
        console.log('data',data);
        var testCases = [];
        var pendingResults = data.length;
        Ext.Array.each(data, function(testcase) {
                    var tc  = {
                        FormattedID: testcase.get('FormattedID'),
                        _ref: testcase.get('_ref'),  
                        Name: testcase.get('Name'),
            ResultsCount: testcase.get('Results').Count,
            Results: []
                    };
            var results = testcase.getCollection('Results');
            results.load({
            fetch: ['Verdict','Date','Build'],
            callback: function(records, operation, success){
                Ext.Array.each(records, function(result){
                tc.Results.push({_ref: result.get('_ref'),
                                                 Verdict: result.get('Verdict'),
                         Date: result.get('Date'),
                         Build: result.get('Build'),
                                });
                },this);
                --pendingResults;
                 if (pendingResults === 0) {
                                        this.updateGrid2(testCases);
                                    }
            },
            scope:this
            });
                testCases.push(tc);

                  }, this);  
    },

     updateGrid2: function(testCases){
        console.log(testCases);
         var store = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                data: testCases,
                pageSize: 100
            });
        if (!this.down('#g2')) {
        this.createGrid2(store);
        }
        else{
        this.down('#g2').reconfigure(store);
        }
     },

     createGrid2: function(store){
        console.log("load grid", store);
        var that = this;



        var g2 = Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.Grid', {
            id: 'g2',
            store: store,

            columnCfgs: [
            {
               text: 'Formatted ID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID', xtype: 'templatecolumn',
            tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate')
            },
            {
            text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name',
            },
            {
            text: 'Results Count', dataIndex: 'ResultsCount',
                    },
            {
                    text: 'Results', dataIndex: 'Results', flex:1,
                    renderer: function(value) {
                        var html = [];
                        Ext.Array.each(value, function(result){
                            html.push('<b>Verdict:</b> ' + result.Verdict + '<br />' + '<b>Date:</b> ' +  Rally.util.DateTime.toIsoString(result.Date,true) + '<br />' + '<b>Build</b> ' + result.Build + '<br />')
                        });
                        return html.join('<br /><br />');
            }
            }
            ]
        });
        this.down('#childPanel2').add(g2);
     }
});
```